# Creating a grid from map model with obstacles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple tower defense map with the road is for the enemy (which is the player can't build the tower there), and the other is for the tower can build there and with any obstacles (trees, rocks, etc).. However, i am not sure on how to make a grid (probably 2x2) loop through the map size and with differentiate with "red" for the obstacles and the road (I am thinking on using the Layer Mask to achieve this), and "white" for the tower can build there.

My map is like below (the red color is for the obstacles and the road, and the green color is for the tower that can build)

Image:

[image]

But the problem is, I can't get it started and I am not sure where to start.

1. Create a grid (probably 2x2) loop through the map size.
2. Place a tower within the "white" color, and not "red" color.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for but checkout Unity's NavMesh, NavMesh Agent and NavMesh obstacle. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy task so I think you'd better use an existing grid generating and path-finding solution. I recommend Aron Granberg's [A* Pathfinding Project](http://arongranberg.com/astar/).

It can create a grid from you map mesh and mark regions as red or obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a `Box Collider` for your road,  you can allow the player to make a *tower* as long as the `GameObject` *tower* is not colliding with your `Box Colider`. You can do the same for your enviroment.